# How to create a SCNNode with a custom geometry?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to create a SCNNode whose geometry is created using an array of x, y, and z positions. I am using the following code; however, this is not showing up. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
class CustomShapeNode: SCNNode {
    init(positions: [(Double, Double, Double)]) {
        super.init()
        
        // Create an array of SCNVector3 from the positions array
        var scnPositions = [SCNVector3]()
        for position in positions {
            scnPositions.append(SCNVector3(Float(position.0), Float(position.1), Float(position.2)))
        }
        
        // Create a geometry from the positions array
        let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [SCNGeometrySource(vertices: scnPositions)], elements: [SCNGeometryElement(indices: Array(0..<scnPositions.count), primitiveType: .triangles)])
        
        // Set the geometry to the node
        self.geometry = geometry
        
        // Set the color of the node geometry
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: To construct a proper SCNGeometry you will need the vertices (the position data, you already have), then you should also calculate the normals for each vertex and you will need the indices, that describes, how the triangles finally are stitched together. This here might help you: https://github.com/aheze/CustomSCNGeometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sceneView: SCNView? = nil
    
    let node = CustomShapeNode([SCNVector3( 0,0,0),       // CCW
                                SCNVector3( 1,1,0),
                                SCNVector3(-1,1,0)])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView = self.view as? SCNView
        sceneView?.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView?.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        sceneView?.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView?.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}

class CustomShapeNode: SCNNode {
        
    init(_ positions: [SCNVector3]) {
        super.init()
        
        let normalsPerFace = 1
        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1, 2]

        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [positions[0],
                                                  positions[1],
                                                  positions[2]])

        let normals = [positions[0],positions[1],positions[2]].map {
            [SCNVector3](repeating: $0, count: normalsPerFace)
        }.flatMap { $0 }

        let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals)
        let data = Data(bytes: indices,
                        count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)

        let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: data,
                                primitiveType: .triangles,
                               primitiveCount: 1,
                                bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
        
        let p1 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(positions[0].x),
                         y: CGFloat(positions[0].y))
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(positions[1].x),
                         y: CGFloat(positions[1].y))
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(positions[2].x),
                         y: CGFloat(positions[2].y))
            
        let texCoord = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: [p1, p2, p3])
                    
        self.geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source, normalSource, texCoord],
                                   elements: [element])
                
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.systemOrange
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .constant
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Hasn't been implemented yet")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful! I am still having an issue seeing the object from certain angles because the material coloring seems to be off. Do you know how to color the entire geometry?

Comment: It depends on how your geometry was created. Ask one more question on SO.